# sbt use diverging scalaVersion for dependencies and compiler (Dotty nightly)

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, dotty, scala-3

I want to test a project against latest Dotty 0.28 nightly builds, while it requires many dependencies that have last been published for Dotty 0.27.0-RC1. Without going into the question of binary compatibility, is there—for testing purposes, to see if a fix in Dotty applies to the project that previously crashed dotc—a way to specify in `build.sbt` **diverging scala versions** for the compiler that's used (I want 0.28.0-...-NIGHTLY) and the dependencies looked up (I want 0.27.0-RC1)?

I do not wish to edit all of `libraryDependencies` to change `% "foo"` for `% "foo_0.27.0-RC1"`, but want a global way to enable this behaviour.

Comment: wow, this is a great question, and I saw the answer not too long ago (can't remember where).   hopefully someone will reply soon ...

Comment: I have to say, though, that it may not achieve anything. I had a test a while ago somehow managing 0.28-nightly compiler and 0.27-RC1 libraries to come together, but the binary interface was broken/incompatible.